# Doctrine MongoDB find by id

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using odm mongo doctrine and I have to document-classes

```
class Thing
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

 /**
  * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Bundle1:Other")
  */
protected $other;
}
```

and

```
class Other
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;
}
```

so in the database a thing looks like :

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("43z758634875adf"),
  "other":ObjectId("38z287348d8se")
}
```

How can I now query for things where other is a given id ?

```
    $dm=$this->mongo->getManager();
            $answers=$dm
                ->createQueryBuilder('Bundle1:Thing')
                ->field('other')->equals("ObjectId(516c0061975a299edc44b419)")  // <-- ?
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute()->count();
```

This produces a wrong mongo query

> MongoDB query:
>   {"find":true,"query":{"other":"ObjectId(516c0061975a299edc44b419)"},"fields":[],"db":"maself","collection":"thing"}
>   [] []

When I use

> ->field('other')->equals("516c0061975a299edc44b419")

the query is also wrong

> MongoDB query:
>   {"find":true,"query":{"other":"516c0061975a299edc44b419"},"fields":[],"db":"maself","collection":"thing"}
>   [] []

So how can I search for thing where other id equals an objectId ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
->field('other')->equals(new \MongoId("516c0061975a299edc44b419"))
```

ObjectId is the internal type for Mongo, represented by \MongoId() in PHP

( But i have also answered in the first topic )

Comment: I've got an exception In ClassMetadata.php line 515: Cannot use object of type MongoId as array