# Doctrine-ODM (MongoDB) - FindByMultipleIDs

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, odm

I am using Doctrine ODM(MongoDB). I am trying to write doctrine odm query builder to get the data where IDs IN (1,2,3). But i am not able to get it. Please help me on this.

I want to create odm query builder for the normal sql query like below,

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

I hope there is no default function like `findByID()`

Comment: I don't know much about PHP/Doctrine, but the query you are looking for is `db.collection.find({ "id" : { "$in" : [1, 2, 3] } })`. This is similar to [this old SO question about Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018417/doctrine-mongodb-find-by-id), so you may find it useful to help you write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html)  :

```
 $queryBuilder = $dm->createQueryBuilder('User')->field('id')->in([$id1,$id2,$id3]);
 $usersCollection = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();
```

or for a single document:

```
$user = $dm->getRepository('User')->find($id);
```

Comment: Can you give me your email id please? i would like to have contact with you regarding technologies KT..