# Parse Error in MongoDB aggregation in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to execute a MongoDB query in PHP.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in fiename.php on
>   line 55

```
$findCount = array("$group" => (_id => "$createdby", count => ($sum:1))); //Line 55
$cursor = $collection->aggregate($findCount);
```

I went through most of the previously asked questions but couldn't arrive to a solution.

By the way, this is my query in MongoDB

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([{"$group" : {_id:"$createdby", count:{$sum:1}}} ])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline is missing some elements notably the array syntax. The correct syntax should be:

```
$findCount = array(
    array(
        "$group" => array(
            "_id" => "$createdby", 
            "count" => array("$sum" => 1)
        )
    )
);      
$cursor = $collection->aggregate($findCount);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It solved my problem but now I'm getting `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?' in filename.php:63 Stack trace: #0 filename.php(63): MongoCollection->aggregate(Array) #1 {main} thrown in filename.php on line 63`

Comment: Check the answers in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024593)

Comment: I replaced double quotes with single quotes and it worked. Guess php was recognising them as variables earlier. 
Thank you. :)